# Initializing Gradle is taking forever on android studio for Flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter

I'm trying to run a hello world flutter app for the first time on my device, but when I hit run on android studio, it shows initilizing gradle, and it stays like that for more than 20 minutes with no logging or error, I have an intel i5 as a CPU and I'm running it on Linux (dual boot, my download speed is quite slow (200 kb/s average download rate), in case this help

I installed the Flutter SDK and when I try `adb devices` on my machine it shows my device connected .

So why it's taking that time to run ? (until now it didn't run yet)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15106

Please note riftninja's answer.
I look at this directory: C:\Users\myname.gradle\wrapper\dists
Yes, the gradle file is really big: 87M. You have to wait for a long time.
After this will be "Resolving dependencies....", which also slowly.
But finally it succeed.

Comment: I confirm this answer. It just takes a looong time (but not forever).

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the same problem, and my internet is currently very slow, so I solved it by changing the gradle in flutter project to an already downloaded one. Just follow these steps:

1. Go to `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\.gradle\wrapper\dists`
2. You should find one or more folders with the name of the distribution (for example with the name "gradle-4.6-all" if you were developing in Android Studio previously), choose one of these folders (make sure it is not empty) and copy its name.
3. Open Android Studio project explorer, and locate `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`
4. You will find a line like this:
   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`
   Change `gradle-5.4.1-all` with the folder name you copied in step 2.
5. Run your app, and hopefully it works this time.

Answer (score 3):

When running flutter project first time even correct configuration it takes very long time.
That is because of downloading gradel and dependencies for particular version.**If you ar noob Wait it to complete automatically till all files get downloaded**. By using command:

- `flutter run <project-name> -v` you can see whats happening in background.
- To Manually downloading gradle zip and put to suitable directory. Go in Project Dir:
  **/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** and click on url and download it.[image: path to get download url]
- After Downloading it visit to :**/Users//.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.2-all/9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv** *your version path may vary*
  and paste downloaded zip inside it.
- For **Dependencies** to download you need to wait depending on Internet speed.
- It is one time process until next updated version and dependencies come UP.

Answer (score 1):

Providing an **active internet connection** worked for me.

To build gradle offline,

For **Windows**,

Go to **File** -> **Settings**.

And open the '**Build,Execution,Deployment**'. Then open the

Build Tools -> **Gradle**

Then **check** the box -> **Offline work** below.

Click the **OK** button.

For **Mac OS**,

go to **Android Studio** -> **Preferences**, and the rest is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Gradle is downloading dependencies and not using any way to show progress, which is **NOT** good for UX. It is better to run `android/gradlew.bat` from your project directory in the terminal and things will become more clear, like this:
[image: running gradlew.bat]

Now it is much better. You can have a cup of coffee while watching it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Goto Android Studio - File - Other Setting - Default Project Structure
Uncheck use Embeded JDk
Below, set your JDK path.
Found in Program files - Java - Jdk.

Answer (score 0):

try to making use of **flutter run -v** which will basically giving the info which is running in background.