# android studio/flutter infinitely says "initializing gradle"

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, error-handling, compiler-errors, flutter

I'm trying to run the demo flutter app through android studio but but whenever I hit run, it says "initializing gradle" on the terminal and never runs the application. I ran the flutter doctor command and it says that there are zero issues so I'm not sure what to do.

[image: The issue]

Comment: how long does it take? could you check the Event Log ?

Comment: I waited like 30 minutes and it worked lol. Thaks for your help mate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing Gradle is taking forever on android studio for Flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773307/initializing-gradle-is-taking-forever-on-android-studio-for-flutter-project)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your Gradle version is above `gradle-4.6-all`
Then, change this property:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

In `gradle-wrapper.properties` file make sure **distributionUrl** is set to your installed `gradle` version. check your `.gradle\wrapper\dists` location for your version. make sure you have `4.6` or above.

Answer (score 0):

you need open projectPath/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, find distributionUrl, download gradle file from distributionUrl, move gradle file(don't unzip file) to 
C:\Users\.gradle\wrapper\dists\\